# A slider through divs

Tags: javascript, html

can someone explain the code below with all functions like `.ready()` and `.next().show().prev().hide();`, `.prev().show().next().hide();`.
And if it's possible, how can I do it JS only without JQuery?
Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".divs div").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").next().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:first").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".divs div:visible").prev().length != 0)
            $(".divs div:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".divs div:visible").hide();
            $(".divs div:last").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="divs">
     <div class="cls1">1</div>
     <div class="cls2">2</div>
     <div class="cls3">3</div>
     <div class="cls4">4</div>
     <div class="cls5">5</div>
     <div class="cls6">6</div>
     <div class="cls7">7</div>
 </div>
 <a id="prev">prev</a>
 <a id="next">next</a>
```

https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/VaBYbZ?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those `.ready()` etc are jQuery methods, its give some shorthand for some JavaScrpit HTML DOM methods. you can look up [this document](https://api.jquery.com/) for those methods

write the same page without jQuery, some function explains are added to code

```js
const prevButton = document.querySelector('#prev'); // same as $('#prev')
const nextButton = document.querySelector('#next');

const cls = document.querySelectorAll('.cls'); // like $('.cls')

let showIndex = 0;

cls[showIndex].classList.add('show');

// .addEventListener('click', function () {...}) like .click(function () {...})
prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cls[showIndex].classList.remove('show');
  showIndex = (showIndex - 1 + cls.length) % cls.length; // like .prev()
  cls[showIndex].classList.add('show');
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  cls[showIndex].classList.remove('show');
  showIndex = (showIndex + 1) % cls.length; // like .next()
  cls[showIndex].classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
.cls {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divs">
  <div class="cls">1</div>
  <div class="cls">2</div>
  <div class="cls">3</div>
  <div class="cls">4</div>
  <div class="cls">5</div>
  <div class="cls">6</div>
  <div class="cls">7</div>
</div>
<a id="prev"><button>prev</button></a>
<a id="next"><button>next</button></a>
```